# I am looking to create a PowerShell script that revokes the user's Azure AD refresh tokens and disable the user's devices

Tags: azure, powershell, token

I am looking for some guidance on combining a PowerShell script that combines the following scripts:

`Connect-AzureAD`

`Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId johndoe@contoso.com`

`Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId johndoe@contoso.com | Set-AzureADDevice -AccountEnabled $false`

What I am hoping to achieve is to combine all three cmdlets to a single script that my staff can run, where it will prompt for the user name that we wish to run the script upon. Assuming I need to add `$ObjectID = Read-Host -Prompt`somewhere in this script.

Thank you in advance for any advice or guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question and you just wanted a way to assemble all that together in the correct order, here it is.

```
# Use one or the other depending on if you want to use the username or objectID
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt
#$ObjectId = Read-Host -Prompt

Connect-AzureAD

# Use one or the other depending on if you want to use the username or objectID
$User = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $Username
#$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $ObjectId

if ($null -ne $User) {
  Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId $User.ObjectId
  Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $User.ObjectId | Set-AzureADDevice -AccountEnabled $false 
} else {
  Write-Warning "No user found with the specified criteria"
}
```